# Show share dialog for Facebook Graph Api - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to share an object which I've create at the objects tab at the open graph section.

```
        FBSDKGameRequestContent *gameRequestContent = [[FBSDKGameRequestContent alloc] init];
        gameRequestContent.message = message;
        gameRequestContent.title = title;
        gameRequestContent.recipients = @[@"400098323516165"];
        gameRequestContent.actionType = actionType;
        gameRequestContent.objectID = @"123456"; //I also tried by the name : bingoclimb:life
        FBSDKGameRequestDialog* dialog = [[FBSDKGameRequestDialog alloc] init];
        dialog.frictionlessRequestsEnabled = YES;
        dialog.content = gameRequestContent;
        dialog.delegate = self;
        [dialog show];
```

My objects section looks like this:

[image]

If I try with this code (with the id) I get the following error:

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.share Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (com.facebook.sdk.share error 2.)" UserInfo=0x170c6cdc0
>   {com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Sorry, this feature
>   isn't available right now: An error occurred while processing this
>   request. Please try again later.}

If I try with the objectId as name I get the following error:

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.share Code=100 "The operation couldn’t
>   be  completed. (com.facebook.sdk.share error 100.)"
>   UserInfo=0x17066eb40
>   {com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Invalid fbid.}

Note: the user has publish_actions permission.

Also, when I copy the creation code from the "Sample code for object" and run it I get the following error:

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.share Code=201 "The operation couldn’t
>   be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.share error 201.)"
>   UserInfo=0x17046a240
>   {com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Error creating Open
>   Graph object: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 8.)"
>   UserInfo=0x1701accc0
>   {NSRecoveryAttempter=<_FBSDKTemporaryErrorRecoveryAttempter:
>   0x170016150>, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=1,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The server is temporarily busy, please
>   try again., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=An unknown
>   error has occurred.,
>   com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=500,
>   com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=1,
>   NSLocalizedRecoveryOptions=(
>       OK ), com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
>       body =     {
>           error =         {
>               code = 1;
>               "fbtrace_id" = "BGhIEBfOI+b";
>               message = "An unknown error has occurred.";
>               type = OAuthException;
>           };
>       };
>       code = 500; }}, NSUnderlyingError=0x17005abb0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 8.)"}

Comment: Are you still seeing this issue? Have you tried updating the SDK to the most recent version as well?

Comment: I still have this issue. 
Do I have to authorise my app before I can do anything?

Comment: How did you fix this damn mess?